# Turn off cron and hook_cron for every module in Drupal

Tags: caching, performance, cron

How can I turn off cron and disable implement of hook_crons in every modules in Drupal
my site is Drupal 6
Thanks

Comment: is this related to "cache gets cleared on every cron run"? just curious

Comment: You can ensure cron is never run by simply never running cron, oddly enough. However, many modules rely on cron and if you don't execute their cron hooks your site may not be fully functional. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh yes, you may need to block the execution of cron.php if it is accessible externally. What sort of hosting are we talking about?

Comment: If you will not set up cron jobs in your server, cron will not work in drupal.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to run cron on your site. You might decide upon the frequency, keep it a high value but it is necessary to run cron to keep your site in healthy state.

If you are worried about loosing the caches when cron is run, you can install [Cache Lifetime Options](https://drupal.org/project/cache_lifetime_options) module and set Minimum Cache Lifetime to a very high value. This will make sure that your caches are not cleared on cron runs. Then you can [Expire module](https://drupal.org/project/expire) for your cache invalidation strategy.

If you do not want to run all the hook_cron implementations but only a selected ones then you should consider using [Elysia Cron module](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron). It lets you run cron for selected modules at selective frequences.